# Validation on input in CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my CakePHP form validation error message not showing while entering data in input field. I want to show validation error message instantly for each input field and I am interested to use CakePHP based settings for this and not using any manual JavaScript codes.

In Yii framework I can display validation error message by using following settings in form-

```
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>TRUE,
    )
```

Now validation error message is displaying after form submit. If anyone is aware about instant validation rules for CakePHP I would like to request them for their advice.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use html5 input tags and the browsers'll do the client side validation. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/
If I remember good, the default CakePHP doesn't support this kind of client side js validation, so you have to write it for yourself or go and search for a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Do you know any best plugins for this that I can use for this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no. We used only the HTML5 tags.

Comment: May be you can use Jquery Validation plugin